# Arduino serial input prompt not repeat

Tags: input, arduino, char, prompt

Following Arduino code purpose is to get a char from user.
Currently problem of continuously prints the prompt.
I want it to print the prompt only once, then wait for the input.
Thanks.

```
char kbChar;
void setup() {Serial.begin(9600);}
void loop() {inChar();}

void inChar(){
    Serial.println("Type something!");
    if(Serial.available()){
        kbChar = Serial.read();
        Serial.println(kbChar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note the following attributes about the `setup()` and `loop()` functions in an Arduino sketch:

- `setup()` is called once, at the very beginning
- `loop()` is called repeatedly, forever, after `setup()` finishes.

Therefore, you are continuing to print the prompt, because your prompt call `Serial.println("Type something!");` is inside of `inChar()`, which is called in the `loop()` function body. To make the prompt output only once, put it in the `setup()` function body.

```c++
char kbChar;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial) ;  // Wait for Serial port to open.
    Serial.println("Type something!");
}
void loop() {
    inChar();
}

void inChar(){
    if(Serial.available()){
        kbChar = Serial.read();
        Serial.println(kbChar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ted. I should have been more clear. I agree with your solution about location of prompt. But I need to get multiple inputs. So I'd like in the loop, but don't want repeated prompts between inputs.

Comment: I think somehow, in the loop, I need to check if something was entered. If it has, then continue loop to read input, use it and repeat the prompt (once). But if no input, then just wait for input.

Comment: I see. Are you trying to store the input somewhere? Right now you only have one character stored (`char kbChar`). This gets overwritten every time you receive new input, so you've lost the previous characters. Is this intentional, losing the previous input characters?